# Popular um array de objetos com uma string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho uma string com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
"Carlos Alberto   xxxxxxx    11/02/2016    $103.10
 Juliano Fontes   xxxxxxx    12/02/2016    $102.10
 Carlos ALberto   xxxxxxx    13/02/2016    $500.00"
```

Tenho meu array com os campos referente a esses dados,com os campos nome, rg, data e valor.
Como ler essa string e jogar linha por linha nos campos do array?

Comment: Ola, Tem um array [] ou JSON {}? Entre dados terá sempre 2 espaços "  "?

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do resultado que queres obter?

Comment: Olá, é uma lista de objetos que vou usar para preencher uma tabela, então seria um json. var lista = { nome[], rg[], data[],value[]}; quero preencher como uma lista simples para popular em uma tabela.

Comment: Os espaços vão ser sempre 2.

Comment: Referes-te aos espaços entre campos de cada linha? Esses serão sempre 2? (Porque no teu exemplo são mais que dois espaços entre campos)

Comment: O @Sergio tem razão. São sempre 2 espaços estre todos os dados? (mesmo entre linhas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui fica mais uma sugestão. Tratar dados dessa maneira é sempre arriscado pois podem infiltra-se erros. Mas cá fica:

```
var texto = document.body.innerHTML.split('\n').filter(Boolean); // só para o exemplo do jsFiddle ir buscar texto
var linhas = texto.map(function(linha) {
    if (linha.match(/^\s+$/)) return; // linhas vazias
    linha = linha.split(/^\s+|\s+$/).join(''); // limpa linhas que começam ou acabam com espaços
    return linha.split(/[\s]{2,}/);
}).filter(Boolean);

var campos = ['nome', 'rg', 'data', 'value'];
var lista = {};

campos.forEach(function(campo, i) {
    lista[campo] = []; // criar a array para cada campo
    linhas.forEach(function(linha) {
        lista[campo].push(linha[i]); // adicionar valor à array
    });
});
console.log(lista);
```

Resultado:

```
{
    "nome": ["Carlos Alberto", "Juliano Fontes", "Carlos ALberto"],
    "rg": ["xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx"],
    "data": ["11/02/2016", "12/02/2016", "13/02/2016"],
    "value": ["$103.10", "$102.10", "$500.00"]
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z7k427pu/

---

Se tens esse texto numa variável basta substituir:

```
var texto = document.body.innerHTML.split('\n').filter(Boolean);
```

por:

```
var texto = tuaVariavel.split('\n').filter(Boolean);
```

Answer (score 1):

WarLock, vejo que esta trabalhando com um arquivo de texto, onde a separação das colunas é feita pelo tamanho da string.

neste caso você vai precisar quebrar o arquivo em linhas, usando o `.split('\n')`, então você vai poder usar uma substring para extrair os campos.

note que este tipo de arquivo, normalmente tem um tamanho fixo para cada linha, por exemplo 60, neste caso você deve verificiar se a linha não é vazia e tem tamanho 60

```js
var nonFloat = /[^\d.\,]/gi;
var arquivo = document.getElementById("arquivo").content.textContent;

var parseDate = function (str) {
  var data = str.split("/");
  return new Date(parseInt(data[2]), parseInt(data[1]), parseInt(data[0]))
}

var registros = arquivo.split("\n").reduce(function (registros, line) {
  var start = 0; 
  var end = 0;
  
  if (line && line.length == 50) {
    var registro = {};
    start = end; end += 18; registro.nome = line.substring(start, end);
    start = end; end += 11; registro.rg = line.substring(start, end);
    start = end; end += 14; registro.data = line.substring(start, end);
    start = end; end += 07; registro.valor = line.substring(start, end);    
    
    registro.nome = registro.nome.trim();
    registro.rg = registro.rg.trim();
    registro.data = parseDate(registro.data);
    registro.valor = parseFloat(registro.valor.replace(nonFloat, ""));
    
    registros.push(registro);
  }
  return registros;
}, []);

console.log(registros);
```

```html
<template id="arquivo">
 Carlos Alberto   xxxxxxx    11/02/2016    $103.10
 Juliano Fontes   xxxxxxx    12/02/2016    $102.10
 Carlos ALberto   xxxxxxx    13/02/2016    $500.00
</template>
```

Comment: O JSON não está como solicitado. var lista = { nome[], rg[], data[],value[]};

Comment: @TiagoGomes, realmente, mas a resposta do Sergio já cobre esta e outros exigencias do AP, vou deixar esta resposta caso o AP perceba que realmente se trata de um `fixed-width text file`.